# Getting Invalid Argument Script Error in Windows 10 IE 11

Tags: javascript

I am getting  Invalid Argument script error in Windows 10 IE 11. 
But In Windows 7 it's working fine.Please check the attached screen shot. Could you please any one help us.
Code look like below :

```
var tbl = document.getElementById('packageMaterial');
var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);
var td1 = row.insertCell(0);
var td2 = row.insertCell(1);
var td3 = row.insertCell(3);
td1.innerHTML = "test1";
td2.innerHTML = "test2";
td3.innerHTML = "test3";
```

In this code I am missing 2 argument to create the cell even though this code works fine in win7 operating system but in win10 IE 11 I am getting Invalid Argument script error. Please check attached error screen shot.

[image: Script Error in Win 10 IE 11]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the below lines of your code.

var tdAvailQty = row.insertCell(3);

var tdPkgId = row.insertCell(5);

In windows 10 IE 11, you need to insert the table columns sequentially, here you are inserting 0,1,2,3 and without inserting 4 you are going with 5.

You can do row.insertCell(4) to come out of that issue.

Hope it helps